# pyinstaller reports missing modules, yet working exe file is created. Is it a non issue?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a working python script I need to turn into an *.exe file. When I run pyinstaller on the script, it finishes with a 'completed successfully' message. The *.exe file runs as expected.

The warn.txt file contains contains about 200 'missing module' warnings.

Here are just a few:

```
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), zipimport (top-level)
```

I've tried adding to pathex and hiddenimports, but it makes no difference. I've also tried importing files at the top of my *.spec file. Still no change in warn.txt. When I run python from the command prompt I can import modules that pyinstaller says are missing.

I'm new to pyinstaller, so I'm wondering-- Should I be concerned about these warnings or just ignore them since the *.exe file appears to be working?

Here's some content from pyinstaller:

```
568 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.13.0
568 INFO: Python: 3.9.0
569 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
```